# How do websites prevent multiple votes without required login

Tags: http, web-applications

A friend of mine showed me a website recently where a person could vote for something. There was no login required, but when I tried to vote more than once (per day), the web site knew. What are possible ways for this to be done?

My first thought was IP address, but I don't think that would work. If I'm in a large office building, work, or public wifi (starbucks, airports, etc) wouldn't it be the case that only 1 person per shared IP address could vote?

What if I drove around the city voting with my phone. If the website were to simply log IPs, wouldn't I theoretically be able to vote once for every cell tower I was close to?

If cookies were used, wouldn't it be possible to disable cookies and vote infinitely?

What mechanism is used to create this type of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly done with a cookie.

It probably tests first that cookies are enabled, and only then lets you vote.

Try voting twice using two different browswers.

Comment: Works. Also works with same browser if you delete the cookies. Is this the _best_ way to prevent multiple votes without requiring a login? Are there any HTTP headers than can be stored server side to help thwart multiple voting?

Comment: Preventing multiple votes is impossible even WITH a login.  Any http request is just a simple, easy hacked, text message, which you have to trust is providing honest information.

Comment: Impossible? Would it not be possible to set a flag associated to that user?